# C# - Problem with using threads (Visual Studio - Windows Forms)

Tags: c#

I'm working on Threadpool app in VS using C#. App is supposed to draw (random)points on the plane in several independent threads and draw them on this plane at a specified speed (pixels per second)in the colors corresponding to the working threads. Number of threads is given by user and it can be from 1 to 10. Points are represented by the pixels on the main form.

What I have done to know:
App is creating 1 thread that uses Draw_Pixel function. After clicking 'Start' button app draw pixels on bitmap and then put the bitmap into the PictureBox on the form. Here is my code:

```
    //int operation_number = 0;
    int x;
    int y;
    int speed;
    int sleep_time;

    List<string> process_list = new List<string>(); 
    Thread [] thread_list = new Thread[12];

   

    //----------------- BUTTONS ------------------------------------------------------------
    private void exit_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {       
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void stop_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        thread_list[0].Abort();
    }

    private void clear_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = null;
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------
    public void start_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //speed = int.Parse(drawing_speed_txt.Text);
        //sleep_time = (1 / speed) * 1000;

        Thread t1 = new Thread(Draw_Pixels);
        t1.Start();
        thread_list[0] = t1;
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------


    //--------------------- FORM LOAD ------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        BindingSource procesy = new BindingSource();
        procesy.DataSource = process_list;
    }
    //---------------- DRAW PIXELS FUNCTION -------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void Draw_Pixels()
    {
        int width = pictureBox1.Width;
        int height = pictureBox1.Height;

        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height);

        Random rand_0_1 = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i <= 100000; i++)
        {
            x = rand_0_1.Next(1, width);

            y = rand_0_1.Next(1, height);

            bmp.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Red);

            pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }

    }    
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

}
```

}

[View on the form while drawing pixels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIL4k.png)

And know I completely don't know what to do next. I need some hints or little guidance.
Btw. I have problem with setting speed given by user. If I put any variable in the Timer.Sleep(var) for ex. 'int speed' instead of direct number of miliseconds, I've got an error says: "System.InvalidOperationException: "The object is currently being used elsewhere."

Thank you so much for any help or hints for this

Comment: You have to lock the object when it is used by another thread. Please search on the internet for "thread-safe" code so you can understand what I'm saying

Comment: You shouldn't be using a PictureBox control in any thread except the main thread.  `pictureBox1.Image = bmp` needs to happen on the main thread.  Once you assign that Bitmap to your PictureBox, you shouldn't be accessing that Bitmap from any other thread except the main thread.   Also, you'll probably only want to update your user interface 60 times per second.  The whole structure of what you have set up so far is unfortunately not headed in the right direction at all.